# Mongo cyclic dependency detected while creating index

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

I have a data with structure like this: 
[image]

And I try to write a query **$near**. For this query, I have to create index, but I get error **cyclic dependency detected** . Here is my code:

define model

```
var answers = new Schema({
  countdown: String,
  location: Object,

}, {
  collection: 'test'
});
var Model = mongoose.model('Model', answers);
```

build and call query

```
    Model.collection.createIndex({ "point": "2dsphere" });
    //query = { location : { $near : [ -120.24, 39.21 ], $maxDistance: 0.10 } }

    query = {
      location: {
        $near: {
          $geometry: {
            coordinates: [-120.24, 39.20  ]
          },
          $maxDistance: 1000
        }
      }
    }

  }
  Model.find(query, function ...)
```

Could you please help me to solve it?..

Answer (score 0):

You can use **MONGO SHELL** to create indices. Login with the connection string and select your **DB** and **Collection** and run

```
db.collection_name.createIndex({"field_name": "indexing value"})
```

This should solve the issue.

Answer (score 0):

`location.coordinates` field must be an array of numbers, in your case it is an array of strings. You should change the fields type to `Double`.